# how can I write this statement in equation form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $x$ men take $5$ days to reap a fields, how long will one men take?

I know its answer will be $5x$ but I don't know how to write this statement in equation form.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

$x$ men need $t = 5$ days for $A = 1$ field.

$1$ man needs $t = 5$ days for $A = 1/x$ field, thus $x \cdot 5$ days for $x\cdot 1/x = 1$ field.

Answer (score 0):

Total number of work days = Number of workers times number of days they take

work days = $5x$

New situtation:-

How long = work days divided by number of workers

How long = $5x \div 1 = 5x$